# Tomcat character encoding

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, character-encoding, tomcat7

I am using the below code to get the response from the API,

```
         String urlRequest = "<actual URL>";

        //Setting the url to the URL object
        URL url = new URL(urlRequest);

        //opening connection that to get the response
        URLConnection urc = url.openConnection();

        //reading the response in the input stream
        BufferedReader brdr = new BufferedReader(new 
                               InputStreamReader(urc.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer resBuf = new StringBuffer();
        String tempStrRes = new String();
        System.out.println(tempStrRes);
```

I get the correct encoded response from my tomcat for the other language characters, But when I use some other tomcat, encoding is not handled properly and the other language characters displayed as ???????.

I checked the server.xml file for both the tomcat machines and they are identical.

I can get the correct response by modifying the code like as follows,

```
   BufferedReader brdr = new BufferedReader(new 
                               InputStreamReader(urc.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
```

But I want to know the the cause of the issue(Content encoded properly in one tomcat but not in another), Is there anything has to configured for the request forwarded from the tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs for `InputStreamReader`, they are very clear:

> Creates an InputStreamReader that uses the **default charset**.

So unless you specify a charset explicitly it will use the system charset, which seems to be different on the two machines. So always specify charsets as a rule of thumb and you're fine, as you found out already.